# Asymptotics of Binomial coefficients

Tags: asymptotics, binomial-coefficients, analytic-combinatorics

I have the following expression

$$\binom{p-q}{\frac{p-q}{2}}-\binom{p-q}{\frac{p-q}{2}-1}=\frac{(p-q)!}{(\tfrac{p-q}{2})!(\tfrac{p-q}{2}+1)!},$$

where $p$ and $q$ are nonnegative integers with $p\geq q$. I have been trying to obtain an asymptotic formula for this expression as $p$ grows using Stirling's approximation:

$$\log{(n!)}= n\log{n}-n+\frac{1}{2}\log{(2\pi)}+\frac{1}{2}\log{n}+O(\tfrac{1}{n}).$$

Applying this approximation to this entire expression yields quite a large formula so I'll not reproduce it here, but every time I try and do this I end up with an asymptotic formula that is incorrect, usually by a factor of $e$. For example, consider the second factorial in the denominator:

$$\log{(((p-q)/2+1)!)}=((p-q)/2+1)\log{((p-q)/2+1)}-((p-q)/2+1)+\frac{1}{2}\log{(2\pi)}+\frac{1}{2}\log{((p-q)/2+1)}+O(\tfrac{1}{((p-q)/2+1)}).$$

Now as $p$ grows very large, what should this expression reduce to? Is it

$$(p/2)\log{(p/2)}-p/2+\frac{1}{2}\log{(2\pi)}+\frac{1}{2}\log{(p/2)}+O(\tfrac{1}{((p-q)/2)}),$$

or

$$((p-q)/2)\log{((p-q)/2)}-((p-q)/2)+\frac{1}{2}\log{(2\pi)}+\frac{1}{2}\log{((p-q)/2)}+O(\tfrac{1}{((p-q)/2)}),$$

or something else?

Comment: Maybe helpful: If $p-q$ is even, your expression is the $p-q$th Catalan number. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number

Comment: Thanks Byron, I had certainly noticed this and of course the Catalan numbers have a known asymptotic formula. I'm more interested in how one might use the above form of Stirling's approximation to derive the result, since I have some other (less friendly) factorials I want to approximate.